# Trying to use specific range in select statement but include all in outer join

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to create a table that will show the annual sales for a given year but return all accounts without sales that year as $0.  I don't want to filter through the WHERE clause because I want the full left join of all accounts.    When I don't specify the date range I can get a total of ALL sales with accounts without sales as null.

I've looked through the questions but can't seem to find an answer.

```
SELECT
   DA.Account_Name,
   sum(fs.total_sales) as total_annual_sales
FROM
   Dim_Account as da
   left outer join
   Fact_Sales as fs
    on da.account_key=fs.account_key

WHERE fs.date_key >=20100101 AND fs.date_key<=20101231

GROUP BY
    da.account_key
ORDER BY
    da.account_name
```

Results look like

```
Account Name     Total_Annual_Sales
Bob's Furniture    100,000
Mary's Emporium     17,000
Joe's Warehouse    150,000
```

However if I DON"T include the dates I get the total of ALL sales EVER

```
Account Name     Total_Annual_Sales
Bob's Furniture    451,000
Gene's Garage        5,000
Mary's Emporium     34,000
Frank's Furnishing    NULL
Joe's Warehouse    250,700
Harry's House         NULL
```

What I WANT to see is sales JUST from 2010

```
Account Name    Total_Annual_Sales
Bob's Furniture   100,000
Gene's Garage           0
Mary's Emporium    17,000
Frank's Furnishing      0
Joe's Warehouse    150,000
Harry's House           0
```

Comment: how about some data so we can see whats the issue

Comment: @JohnRuddell see update above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding the filter on the date when you join the table.. if its a left join it should have the null values in there... then coalesce the sum to show a 0 if its null.. if this doesn't work please post a sqlfiddle with some sample data so I can get it to work. should be a simple fix.

sample query:

```
SELECT
   DA.Account_Name,
   IF (SUM(fs.total_sales)> 0, SUM(fs.total_sales), 0) as total_annual_sales
FROM Dim_Account as da
LEFT JOIN Fact_Sales as fs
  ON da.account_key=fs.account_key
 AND (fs.date_key >=20100101 AND fs.date_key<=20101231)
GROUP BY da.account_key
ORDER BY da.account_name
```

Comment: So smart.  I didn't realize you could add the date range to the join.  I'll give it a go.  Thanks!!

Comment: thanks John!  I did tweak it a bit as the COALESCE was giving me a BLOB in the result field.  I opted for

    'code'    SELECT
       DA.Account_Name,
       if (sum(fs.total_sales)> 0, sum(fs.total_sales), 0) as total_annual_sales

Comment: It DID.  I'm sorry I can't seem to get the code to show up as code in the comments.  THANK YOU!

Comment: add ` backticks :) to the front and back

Comment: yea I gotcha.. I added that to my answer :)

Comment: @omadison if you could accept this as the correct answer when you have time it would be appreciated :) glad I could help.. good luck with your programming adventures!!